# Why are my JavaScript varables undefined when I load as an extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, youtube

My JavaScript code works fine when manually pasted into a browsers' console. Whenever I load my code as an extension, however, the error report says my 'ratingPair' variable is undefined. If I try declaring my 'views' variable first, then it too will be undefined.

I've tried both Firefox and Chrome browsers, different computers, and disabling other extensions.

ratingRatio.js

```
let ratingPair = document.querySelectorAll("yt-formatted-string.ytd-toggle-button-renderer");

// total = likes + dislikes
let total = Number(ratingPair[0].ariaLabel.replace(/\D/g,'')) +
            Number(ratingPair[1].ariaLabel.replace(/\D/g,''));

let views = Number(document.querySelector(".view-count").innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,''));

if (total)
    document.querySelector(".view-count").innerHTML += " 1/" + Math.round(views/total);
else
    document.querySelector(".view-count").innerHTML += " NA";
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "Displays the ratings/views ratio on Youtube; ratingRatio = (likes + dislikes)/views",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ratingRatio",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
      "js": ["ratingRatio.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The ratio should append itself next to the views. For example, if a video has 20,395 views, 475 likes, and 10 dislikes, then we can compute the ratio by:

(475 + 10)/20,395 ≈ 1/42

Thus, below the video should read, "20,395 views 1/42"

Comment: one explanation: your content script is running *before the relevant html elements exist in the DOM*

Comment: @JaromandaX I used a setTimeout function to delay the script by several seconds. Now I'm getting, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined", which is a step further from before. This code still works when I manually paste it in.

Comment: `ratingPair[0].ariaLabel` is probably undefined then - though, using setTimeout is a kludge, not a solution

Comment: @JaromandaX I should have asked this earlier, how do I make the content script wait for relevant html elements?

Comment: [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)